# Regex not matching as one group

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a numerical value like `xx.xx`, `xx.x` or `x.x` in a string that may be represented with, or without a asterisk.

```
*10.00
5.0
```

But ***not*** match singular digits

```
*1
5m
```

and replace it with a colored version, but my pattern is not matching the whole element in the string, but multiple parts

Here is what I have tried: https://ideone.com/vZwCzh

```
String string = "*10.00 5.0 *1 5m";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("([\\*?0-9.]){3,15}", "<span style=\"color:yellow\">$1</span>"));
```

I get

```
<span style="color:yellow">0</span> <span style="color:yellow">0</span> *1 5m
```

Instead of

```
<span style="color:yellow">*10.00</span> <span style="color:yellow">5.0</span> *1 5m
```

Comment: You put a limiting quantifier into a character class, and `{1,13}` is treated as a set of chars.

Comment: `[0-9{1,13}.]`? Do you mean `[0-9.]{1,13}`?

Comment: I see a wrong use of character classes here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, and everyone else. My pattern should be: `([\\*?0-9.]){1,15}` Don't know if it's perfect. I added two character to the character count from 13 to 15 for the possible * and . that I didn't think about. Not sure I that was called for.

Comment: @JordanSasquatchMan `([\\*?0-9.]){1,15}` is wrong too. You now put `\\*?` inside the character class. Don't.

Comment: You say to match `double` and only show examples of unsigned values with `.` in them. You then say to not match singular digits. Does that mean that a value like `10` is ok to match? How about `1e0`? Or `-2.5`? Or `NaN`? When you say to match `double`, it sounds like all valid `double` representations, as defined by [Double.valueOf(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-). Is that really what you want? Your own attempt suggests otherwise, so you're not really trying to match `double`. Please edit question and clarify.

Comment: @Andreas I guess I don't mean doubles. I just mean how the `double` are parsed and always display compared to the `int` values displayed as single digits in all available output from the program. I'll remove that.

Comment: Does that mean you don't want to match `10`? Or `-2.5`? Only unsigned values with a `.` and at least one digit on each side of the `.`? If so, then use `replaceAll("\\*?\\d+\\.\\d+", "<span style=\"color:yellow\">$1</span>")`

Comment: `xx.x` or `xx.x` or yes, `x.x` with optional `*` prefix. Like `*10.00 10.0 5.0`

Comment: Also @Andreas I've tried that same basic setup originally, it doesn't even match. You can try easily here: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

Comment: Sure it does: https://ideone.com/10dZD7. Just had to replace `$1` with `$0`, since no capture group was defined.

Comment: Interesting. Both in the program, and in the tester it comes back with no changes, and: `No match found! .matches() method: false .lookingAt() method: false` I am using `$0`.

Comment: Oh I didn't actually run the changes in the program, and apparently Java tester ***only*** uses the `matcher()` and `lookingAt()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this :
`\*?\d(?:\d\.\d\d?|\d?\.\d)`
by this :
`<span style="color:yellow">$0</span>`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/axYyiS/4)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be for Java, though it may work. But is there a way to make it not capture singular digits?

Comment: @JordanSasquatchMan: It should work with any regex engine. I update my answer to skip singular digits

Comment: In Java, the replacement string should contain `$1`, not ``\1``.

Comment: @JordanSasquatchMan: I edited my answer to match exactly `xx.xx`, `xx.x` and `x.x` as you asked

Comment: @Andreas: Good catch, it is changed